# Why do ArcPy SQL expressions use three double quotes?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, where-clause

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.4 and I am trying to understand why ArcPy SQL expressions use three double quotes. ESRI's "Specifying a query in Python" page, https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/specifying-a-query.htm, 
gives two examples of using SQL statements (both of which seemingly have where clauses of `"roadclass" = 2` wrapped in three double quotes):

Example without field delimiters:

```
import arcpy
fc = "D:/St_Johns/data.gdb/roads"

# Create a search cursor using an SQL expression
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("roadclass", "name"), """"roadclass" = 2""")
for row in cursor:
    print(row[1])
```

Example with field field delimiters:

```
import arcpy
fc = "D:/St_Johns/data.gdb/roads"
fieldname = "roadclass"

# Create field name with the proper delimiters
whereclause = """{} = 2""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fieldname))

# Create a search cursor using an SQL expression
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("roadclass", "name"), whereclause)
for row in cursor:
    print(row[1])
```

It is my impression that SQL statements in a SearchCursor constructor in ArcGIS Pro should have string values enclosed in single quotes and that the overall expression should be in double quotes as in `" PARCEL = 'A2003KSW' "`. That syntax make sense, however I am not understanding the jump from one to three sets of double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Python technique (string literal) that'll allow the tool or arcpy function to make use of quotations in the calculation or where clause. The triple quotes can span multiple lines and will 'escape' the quotes.

In your case: 
`""""roadclass" = 2"""` when evalauted will be:  `"roadclass" = 2` inside the tool.

Alternatively you could write `"\"roadclass\" = 2"`   (that is, \") to escape the quotes.

Comment: Yep.  It's nothing to do with it being SQL.  It's simply one of several ways that Python has to delimit string literals (eg, double quotes, single quotes, and triple-double quotes).  Each method has advantages and different situations where they are preferable.  In this case, the SQL text includes double quotes within it, so it's an easy way to include double quotes without having to escape them.