# What's wrong with my SQL? Invalid Expression

Tags: arcpy, sql

I'm just trying to make it where the user types what county they want and the script selects those features.

```
import arcpy

County = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)    

arcpy.env.workspace = (GDB path)

SelectedField = "COUNTY1"

Expression = (SelectedField + '=' + 'County')

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("ArmoringBackup", "New_Selection", Expression)
```

If I put the county name in the expression, it works fine. The issue I'm having is with making it a parameter that can be changed.

Comment: Maybe this post will help:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356650/why-do-arcpy-sql-expressions-use-three-double-quotes

Answer (score 1):

Here's the new script after figuring it out (still getting used to this website):

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'(GDB Path)'

selectedField = 'COUNTY1'
county = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

sql = "{0} = '{1}'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource="ArmoringBackup", field='COUNTY1'), county)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("ArmoringBackup", "New_Selection", sql)
```

I must've been using the wrong delimiters and the new line does it for you.

Comment: Best practice calls for only using leading uppercase for class names, not variables.